# equation of a line parallel to a given ine at a constant disance?

Tags: analytic-geometry

what is the equation of a line parallel to a given line say y=x at a constant disance of 1 unit from it?
I guess there will be 2 equations,one above x axis and other below x axis

Comment: Equation of any line parallel to $ y=x $ is $ y=x+k $. Find $ k $ according to your requirement. Yes there will be two lines but not the way you described.

Comment: how to find k? using the information that it is at a distance of 1 unit from y=x?

Comment: You can use the formula for distance of a point $(x_1,y_1)$ from the line $ax+by+c=0$, which is given by $\frac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: The required lines are not $y=x+1$ and $y=x-1$ .. !!

Comment: how can they be y=x+1 or x-1!! not possible

Comment: yes they are not the answer ...find $k$ using the above formula

Comment: will the answer be y=x+root(2) and y=x-root(2)?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Answer (score 1):

The distance of a point $P=(x_P,y_P)$ from a stright line of equation $ax+by+c=0$ is given by:
$$
d=\dfrac{|ax_P+by_P+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$
(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line))

so, a generic point $(x,y)$ at distance $1$ from the line is such that:
$$
\dfrac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=1
$$
and , separating the two case for the absolute value, you have the equations of two stright lines.